# Splitting an array to another array

Tags: c#, sql

I have a list which contains

1. The `Price`
2. The `Code`

I've managed to split the list to an array, but I want to further split the array so that I can get the `Price` and `Code` separately and sort the `Price` to ascending order. When the sorting occurs, I need the `Code` to be sorted together as well because the `Price` is for that particular `Code`.

So it will be like this:
Original List:

```
1588,8DNY;1488,ACNY;1288,7DPE;1888,8HUC;1488,8WNH;
```

After Splitting to arrPrice:

```
[1588,8DNY],[1488,ACNY],[1288,7DPE],[1888,8HUC],[1488,8WNH]
```

2nd Splitting 2ndarrPrice:

```
[1588],[1488],[1288],[1888],[1488]
```

2nd Splitting 2ndarrCode:

```
[8DNY],[ACNY],[7DPE],[8HUC],[8WNH]
```

Sort Price in ascending order:

```
[1288],[1488],[1488],[1588],[1888]
```

Code will be sorted accordingly:

```
[7DPE],[ACNY],[8HUC],[8WNH]
```

I am stuck after the 1st splitting.

```
  if (lblprices.Text != "")
    {
        arrprice = lblprices.Text.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        Array.Sort(arrprice);

        for (i = 0; i < arrprice.Length; i++)
        {
            arr2 = arrprice[i].Split(',');
            SQL2 = "SELECT DISTINCT [TP].[TCode], ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[TName], ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[TName_CN],  ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[TourType], ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[LastUpdateDate], ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[ValidityFrom],  ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[ValidityTo], ";
            SQL2 += "[CL].[CountryCode], ";
            SQL2 += "[CL].[CityName] ";

            SQL2 += "FROM [CL], [TP], [TourItinerary],[TourHotel] ";

            SQL2 += "WHERE [TP].[Activation] = 1  ";
            SQL2 += "AND [TP].[TCode] = '" + arr2[1] + "' ";
            SQL2 += "ORDER BY [TP].[LastUpdateDate] DESC ";

            objConnTour.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL2, objConnTour);
            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dataReader.Read())
            {
                html += "<tr><td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["TCode"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["TName"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["TName_CN"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["TType"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["LastUpdateDate"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["ValidityFrom"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["ValidityTo"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["CountryCode"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["CityName"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">from&nbsp;<span class=\"price-red\">S$<b>" + arr2[0] + "</b></span><td/></tr>";
            }

            dataReader.Close();

            objConnTour.Close();
        }
    }
    return html;
```

The code above will not be able to sort the price in ascending order. As you can see in my `arr2` split, I need the `Code` and `Price` together as I will be retrieving data from database based on the `Code`.

--------Edit---------

Ok so the problem is that if the prices are in the of 1000-1999, it gets sorted perfectly.
But if i have prices that is less than 1000, it will not be sorted in an ascending manner

Example are the screenshots of the results using the code provided by @jekcom

This is when i haven't split the List and retrieve them raw from the database

[image: Original, Unsorted]

And this is the Sorted one using @jekcom's code

[image]

Notice how the Price are not sorted in Ascending manner.

Comment: Could you point out where exactly you get an error/is not working?

Comment: jekcom's answer is wrong. Please see mine or codeIgnoto's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't work since you're not sorting the array based on `Price` part of the array. If you have `Linq`:

```
if (lblprices.Text != "")
{
    arrprice = lblprices.Text.Split(new char[] { ';' }, 
                                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var lst = arrprice.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(',')[0])).ToList();

    for (i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
    {
        arr2 = lst[i].Split(',');

        //rest of your code ----------------
    }
```

This should work, in sql terms this should give

```
ORDER BY PRICE ASC, [TP].[LastUpdateDate] DESC
```

Comment: when i tried to run the code, is giving me this error :
'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ymcCole Oh please use `Count` instead of length. These things happen when answers are posted without compiling in our own machines :) Pls find the edit :)

Comment: @ymcCole I personally ask you to opt for CodeIgnoto's answer and accept his answer (though you could upvote both of us) :)

Comment: @nawfal well, yours is also not the most correct answer. I don't know about this particular case, but prices sometimes have decimals. So your code will fail in such case

Comment: @jekcom that's such a trivial point which OP can adjust according to requirement. The main point was to give him an idea. And if you are talking about prices, then your double is not suitable too. The glaring glitch in your original code was something OP wouldn't have noticed. Yes he had to make it another question because of the trivial error in yours

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List` of `KeyValuePair`s and sort them using LINQ.

```
IList<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>> items = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>();
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("8DTY", 1589));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("1DNY", 1688));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("8DNY", 1888));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("8DNY", 1588));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("8ENY", 1589));

IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,decimal>> result =items.OrderBy(item => item.Value);

foreach (var keyValuePair in result)
{
    MessageBox.Show(keyValuePair.Key + " " + keyValuePair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this:

Define your custom comperer to sort your array
then pass it to the sort method

**The comparer**

```
public class ProductComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        string[] _x = x.Split(',');
        string[] _y = y.Split(',');
        double priceY = double.Parse(_y[0]);
        double priceX = double.Parse(_x[0]);

        return priceX.CompareTo(priceY);
    }
}
```

**Your code**

```
if (lblprices.Text != "")
    {
        arrprice = lblprices.Text.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        Array.Sort(arrprice, new ProductComparer());


        for (i = 0; i < arrprice.Length; i++)
        {
            arr2 = arrprice[i].Split(',');
            SQL2 = "SELECT DISTINCT [TP].[TCode], ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[TName], ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[TName_CN],  ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[TourType], ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[LastUpdateDate], ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[ValidityFrom],  ";
            SQL2 += "[TP].[ValidityTo], ";
            SQL2 += "[CL].[CountryCode], ";
            SQL2 += "[CL].[CityName] ";

            SQL2 += "FROM [CL], [TP], [TourItinerary],[TourHotel] ";

            SQL2 += "WHERE [TP].[Activation] = 1  ";
            SQL2 += "AND [TP].[TCode] = '" + arr2[1] + "' ";
            SQL2 += "ORDER BY [TP].[LastUpdateDate] DESC ";

            objConnTour.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL2, objConnTour);
            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dataReader.Read())
            {
                html += "<tr><td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["TCode"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["TName"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["TName_CN"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["TType"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["LastUpdateDate"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["ValidityFrom"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["ValidityTo"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["CountryCode"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">" + dataReader["CityName"] + "</td>";
                html += "<td class=\"border\">from&nbsp;<span class=\"price-red\">S$<b>" + arr2[0] + "</b></span><td/></tr>";
            }

            dataReader.Close();

            objConnTour.Close();
        }
    }
    return html;
```

**Array result**

```
1288,7DPE
1488,ACNY
1488,8WNH
1588,8DNY
1888,8HUC
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Please dont do string comparison in place of number comparison. This gives wrong result in case of 2 and 12 as prices. Please have an int.Parse in your string comparer

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do using Linq

```
string s = "1588,8DNY;1488,ACNY;1288,7DPE;1888,8HUC;1488,8WNH";

var OrderedResult= s.Split(';').ToList<string>()
                    .Select(item => item.Split(','))
                    .Select(item => new { price = Int32.Parse(item[0]), code = item[1] })
                    .OrderBy(item => item.price);

foreach(var item in OrderedResult)
{
   var sql = "select ..... where price=" + item.price + " and code=" + item.code;
   execute(sql);
}
```

Comment: I just edited your code to make the anonymous type better, hope its ok :)